# Node http.request not working

Tags: node.js, client

I am trying to create a simple server and a simple client with node.js using http module. Server is working fine but client is not. Please help me to find the bug...
Server Is :

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
server.on('request', function(req, res){
    res.end("hello, world");
});
server.listen(4000);
```

Client Is :

```
var options = {
    host   : 'localhost',
    port   : 4000,
    method : 'GET',
    path   " '/'
};
require('http').request(options, function(res){
    console.log(require('util').inspect(res));
    res.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

I am running them in different terminal windows as **node server.js** & **node client.js**.

I am getting below mentioned error on the client.js running terminal after around 10 mins.

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1473:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1569:23)
at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `request()` method of the HTTP library will not automatically end requests, therefore they stay open, and time out. Instead, you should either end the request using `req.end()`, or use the `get()` method, which will do so automatically.

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // handle the resposne
});
req.end();
```

Or:

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
  // handle the resposne
});
```